# random: what is the default seed?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For Python 3, I can find many different places on the internet stating that the default seed for the `random` module is based on system time.

Is this also the case for Python 2.7? I imagine it is, because if I start two different Python processes, and in both I do `import random; random.random()` then the two different processes return different results.

If it does use system time, what is the actual seed used? (E.g. "number of seconds since midnight" or "number of microseconds since UNIX epoch", or ...)
If not, what is used to seed the PRNG?

Answer (score 8):

This is the source code about how to generate default seed for a `Random` object.

```
try:
    # Seed with enough bytes to span the 19937 bit
    # state space for the Mersenne Twister
    a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(2500)), 16)
except NotImplementedError:
    import time
    a = long(time.time() * 256) # use fractional seconds
```

`urandom` equals to `os.urandom`. And for more information about `urandom`, please check this [page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom).

Comment: Okay if i get you well, this is how Python will determine the seed to use if none is provided. Okay where can I see the code implementation of  ```_urandom```

Comment: I think this source code is for Python 2 or it's outdated. Per my checking in the latest Python 3 source code, the default time-based seed is [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e50112/Modules/_randommodule.c#L258C1-L258C1) which seems to use [GetSystemClock](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e50112/Python/pytime.c#L983) and [GetMonotonicClock](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1e50112/Python/pytime.c#L1180). I'm not well-versed in C, but I think perhaps it includes _at least_ milliseconds or a finer precision.