# How does Python's random use system time?

Tags: python, random

I've searched around but couldn't find an explanation. Please help me. Thanks.

I understand that Python will use system's time if a seed is not provided for random (to the best of my knowledge). My question is: How does Python use this time? Is it the timestamp or some other format?

I ran the following code;

```
from time import time
import random

t1 = time() #this gave 1590236721.1549928
data = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
t2 = time() #this also gave 1590236721.1549928
```

Since `t1 == t2`, I guessed that if UNIX timestamp is used as seed, it should be `t1` but after trying it like so;

```
random.seed(t1)
data1 = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
```

I got different values: `data != data1`.

I need more explanations/ clarifications. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2

In this Q&A : (for python2.7) [random: what is the default seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443356/random-what-is-the-default-seed) You can see that python is not using the result of the `time()` function "as-is" at all to get the initial seed (and usually, it tries to get `urandom` values if it can from the OS, first, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom.

```
try:
    # Seed with enough bytes to span the 19937 bit
    # state space for the Mersenne Twister
    a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(2500)), 16)
except NotImplementedError:
    import time
    a = long(time.time() * 256) # use fractional seconds
```

## Python 3

a) As in Python 2, if your OS provides random numbers (with [`urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom)), like in *Nix systems, Python will try to use this (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#bookkeeping-functions). On Windows, it's using [Win32 API's `CryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom)

b) even if it is using time(), maybe it's using the time at the start of your program, which may be different than the first `time()` call you use, so I don't think you can rely on your method of testing.

Last word of general advice: if you want reproducibility, you should explicitly set the seed yourself, and not rely on those implementation details.

Comment: From my findings in the related question you posted, Python will first make a call to ```_urandom``` for randomness and then use ```long(time.time() * 256)``` if it's not implemented (if ```NotImplementedError``` is raised). The part that catches the exception is clear. Where can I see the code implementation for ```_urandom```. It's not in the docs link you shared. I also got that ```_urandom``` is OS-specific. I would like the see that for Windows. Thanks.

Comment: For python 3, in https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom, there is a specific line for Windows : `On Windows, it will use CryptGenRandom().`, which is a function from the [Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) (not sure if the source is available).

Comment: So, as I understand currently, if you're on Windows, then the default seed is not the system time.

Answer (score 0):

when you use the program more than once without hitting in the seed you're using the utc down to the second, so you get a different results each time.

every nano second will give you a different time.

try this:

```
import random

print ("Random number with seed 42")
random.seed(42)
print ("first Number ", random.randint(1,99))

random.seed(42)
print ("Second Number ", random.randint(1,99))

random.seed(42)
print ("Third Number ", random.randint(1,99))
```